# Different ways of Iterating over a list

Tags: python, list, slice

Can somebody tell me what's the difference between this code:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in x[:]:
    if i == 5:
        x.insert(0, i)
```

And this code:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in x:
    if i == 5:
        x.insert(0, i)
```

Why doesn't the second one work? I know it is mentioned in the Python tutorial, but I can't quite understand it.

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Just `x.insert(0, 5)` would work for this example

Comment: That's not the point, I'm trying to understand the mechanics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first version, you create a copy (by slicing the list from the beginning to the end), in the second one you're iterating over the original list.

If you iterate over a container, its size can't change during iteration, for good reasons (see below). But since you call `x.insert`, the size of your list changes.

---

If you execute the second version, it actually doesn't throw an error immediately, but continues indefinitely, filling the list up with more and more 5s:

Once you're at the list index 4 (and `i` is therefore 5), you're inserting a 5 at the beginning of the list:

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

You then continue in the loop, implicitly increasing your index to 5, which is now again 5, because the whole list got shifted one to the right, due to your insertion, so 5 will be inserted again:

```
[5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

This goes on "forever" (until there's a `MemoryError`).

Comment: Okey, but if I would add "print(x)" at the end, it would display modified x (with x[0] being 5), so that would indicate that the size of x did actually change

Comment: Also OP should note that both of those approaches will not work in Python 3.x

Comment: @kmario23 Both work in Python 3 exactly like in Python 2.

Comment: @JohnnyJohansson In the second case you are allowed to edit `x`, because you're not really iterating over it, but over a copy.

Comment: @kmario23 the first approach seems to work in Python 3.5

Comment: @JohnnyJohansson Yes. But it does not work in ipython3.4.3

Comment: @kmario23 Tested it with Python 3.4.3 now, too, it does seem to work.